# Not able to emulate Nativescript hello world on ios

Tags: javascript, ruby, xml, xcode, nativescript

When trying to test out a new client app stack known as Nativescript I got this build error:

[image: Terminal Screenshot].

I tried running a build from a different project on an ios emulator which then got the same error. When running the nativescript CLI command *tns doctor*(command which checks to see if the Nativescript CLI is properly installed)it seemed to be installed correctly. I can see that some ruby command wasn't being executed correctly but don't know how I would go about fixing it.

Comment: which version of NS are you using?

Comment: try to do a clean build. tns platform remove ios and after that tns run ios

Comment: Also try using tns run ios --bundle if you are using Vue. tns run ios command will not work for vue.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I figured it out, it was trying to run a ruby command with xcodeproj but I hadn't installed xcodeproj. The command that fixed it was "sudo gem install xcodeproj"